# How to use css inside a controller in rails without view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller from where I want to render :plain text, the text is string and I want it in a class (a css class not the oops one) which is present in style.css and located in assets/stylesheets folder. But since render does not put css link href, how can I do this?
I can't just output a `<link href="" ...` because it will then give error of no get path as only views are viewable.

edit:
to those people who are asking why I am not using views?
because I am using render, so views don't work.

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use views? Why try to break a working system?

Comment: render json: {some_nasty_html: render_to_string("/to/your/template/with/css/inside")}

Comment: @BooVeMan because i am using render json, so I can't use views

Comment: if you render json you won't need css

Comment: @BooVeMan Then how will I design my data? i am getting json for a javascript that makes an ajax request, not a static page

Comment: @user1735921the page that issues the ajax request should link the css.

Comment: @BooVeMan yeah got it now, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Create new [layout](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html) with css files included.

Another way (ugly!) is to

```
render "<link rel="stylesheet ... >#{some text from rails method}".html_safe
```